# Office menu control using Add-in

Tags: c++, vsto, add-in

I have developed a plugin to control the enable state of a specified menu and ribbon control in Office 2016.

XML files follow this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">

  <commands>    
    <command idMso="FileSendAsAttachment" enabled="false"/>
    <command idMso="FileEmailAsPdfEmailAttachment" enabled="false"/>
    <command idMso="FileEmailAsXpsEmailAttachment" enabled="false"/>
    <command idMso="FileInternetFax" enabled="false"/>
    ...

  </commands>  

  <ribbon>
  </ribbon>

  <backstage>    
  </backstage>

</customUI>
```

After installing the add-in, depending on the policy, the agent may need to temporarily enable certain menus. 
So, I modified only the enable property of the control in the XML file and restarted Office, but all the menus are enabled.
(However, when I replace it with the original XML file, it is marked as disable again.)

My addin was registered via regsvr32.exe, and the registry was written in HKCU.
(Windows is 64bit, Office 2016 is 32bit.)

Has anyone had a similar problem?
What is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

After installing the add-in, I modified the XML file using notepad. And I found that it is stored in utf-8 encoding way.

I noticed that the format is broken because the BOM is inserted in the first byte of the XML file. If you save the file as ANSI, it works fine.

I hope you will not make the same mistake as me !

Answer (score 0):

use utf-16

```
  <commands>    
    <command idMso="FileSendAsAttachment" enabled="false"/>
    <command idMso="FileEmailAsPdfEmailAttachment" enabled="false"/>
    <command idMso="FileEmailAsXpsEmailAttachment" enabled="false"/>
    <command idMso="FileInternetFax" enabled="false"/>
    ...

  </commands>  

  <ribbon>
  </ribbon>

  <backstage>    
  </backstage>

</customUI>
```